# get QRect of menus in QMenuBar

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmenubar

I am re-implementing the mouseMoveEvent in a QMenuBar to allow me to click-drag a frameless application around (basically just making my own frame around my app). However I am trying to disable this behavior whenever the mouse is over a QMenu item, which gives strange behavior (the windows starts following your mouse when you click on a menu!).

I thought this would be as simple as calling the QMenuBar's `self.childrenRect().contains(event.pos())` however this does not work. From what I can tell `self.childrenRect()` does not actually return the rect of the QMenu items. So what is the "correct" way to do this?

Here's my subclassed QMenuBar for reference:

```
class MoveMenu(QtGui.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MoveMenu, self).__init__()
        self.mouseStartLoc = QtCore.QPoint(0,0)
        self.set_move = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(MoveMenu, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self.mouseStartLoc = event.pos()

        # this is always testing False
        if not self.childrenRect().contains(event.pos()):
            self.set_move = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(MoveMenu, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if self.set_move:
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            self.parent().move(globalPos - self.mouseStartLoc)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(MoveMenu, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.set_move = False
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give me the rect of the whole menubar, which would never test False? That defeats the purpose - when the user clicks on the menu I want to be able to move the app, just not when they click on a "button"

Comment: It is working once I super'd the mousePressEvent. I admit my knowledge of "super" is pretty limited so I can't explicitly tell you WHY it works... but it does! Curiously if I call a specific child with self.children()[1].rect() everything works as expected. So why is self.childrenRect() not working? Is this just a bug?

Comment: That is correct. Which is why I am trying to test if the mousePressEvent is on a menu, in which case I disable the drag operation and "pass through" the click as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169821/discussion-between-spencer-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 0):

With help from eyllanesc, here's the working code. self.childrenRect() doesn't work (bug?) but looping manually through the children does.

```
class MoveMenu(QtGui.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MoveMenu, self).__init__()
        self.mouseStartLoc = QtCore.QPoint(0,0)
        self.set_move = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(MoveMenu, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self.mouseStartLoc = event.pos()

        if not any(child.rect().contains(event.pos()) for child in self.children():
            self.set_move = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(MoveMenu, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if self.set_move:
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            self.parent().move(globalPos - self.mouseStartLoc)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(MoveMenu, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.set_move = False
```